# Awk with a variable

Tags: awk

I have an awk command to print out the total number of times "200" occurred in column 26.

```
awk '$26 ~ /200/{n++}; END {print n+0}' testfile
```

How do I modify this statement so I can pass 200 as a variable? e.g. if I have a variable $code with a value of 200

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `code` has the value `20` and the number `200` appears in field 26, should that match or not? Are you looking for a match on the WHOLE of field 26 or only part of it?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$26 ~ code {n++} END {print n+0}' code=200 testfile
```

> If a filename on the command line has the form var=val it is treated as a variable
>   assignment. The variable var will be assigned the value val.

[§ Awk Program Execution](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)

Comment: That's something I didn't know, but wanted to note after looking it up in `The AWK Programming Language`: the filename var=val assignment is `performed at the time when that argument would otherwise be accessed as a file.  This type of assignment allows variables to be changed before and after a file is read.`  Meaning that order is important.

Comment: @n0741337 Correct and variables assigned that way are not available in the BEGIN section which can cause confusion/mistakes. You should only use this method if you need to change a variables value between files, otherwise `awk -v awkvar="$shellvar"` is almost always the right approach. See the article I wrote for the comp.unix.shell FAQ at http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk  -v var="$shellVar" '$26~var{n++} END{print n}' file
```

you see above line how to use shell variable in awk. some notes for your awk one-liner:

- `print n+0` not necessary. because the `n` defined by you, not picked from input text, and you explicitly did `n++`, so it is number type, `n+0` makes no sense
- the `;` before `END` should be removed
- I copied your code about the checking 200 part. but it is risky. if the $26 has only a number, you can consider to use `1*$26 == 200` or `$26 == "200"` using regex in this situation may give wrong result, think about in your $26, value was : `20200`